# Unable to run npm install in pipeline using Artillery container for performance tests

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, pipeline, artillery

I'm currently having issues with my performance tests running in the pipeline. I'm using Artillery to execute performance tests on a nightly CRON schedule and the workflow leverages Artillery's container: `artilleryio/artillery:latest`.

The issue I'm having is I can't run `npm ci` in the pipeline. I haven't been able to find a solution online. The only solution I've seen is `npm clean cache`, but that isn't working.

**Error**:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/local/bin/node /__t/node/16.20.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/github/home/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/jsesc reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/jsesc: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/github/home/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/b6/68'
```

I'm able to run the Artillery perf tests locally. This is only an issue running `npm ci` in the pipeline using the Artillery container.

**Workflow**:

```yaml
jobs:
  performance-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write' 

    environment:
      name: dev

    container: artilleryio/artillery:latest

    steps:
    - name: NPM Clean
      run: npm cache clean --force

    - name: NPM Install
      run: npm ci

    - name: Run Performance Tests
      env:
        # Insert required env variables for e2e tests below 
        AUTHORIZATION_LOGIN_PATH: ""
      run: //home/node/artillery/bin/run run -o notification.json test/performance/perf-tests.yml

    - name: Generate Performance Test
      run: //home/node/artillery/bin/run report --output notification.html notification.json
```

Comment: How do you run your tests locally? What's the sequence of commands that you run to run the container and tests?

Comment: You current configuration means that you're running inside the `container` itself. If that's the case, your checkout step is missing. Without checkout, there'll be no files to work with for `npm` commands. You need to fix that.

Comment: @Azeem locally I just execute using Artillery's cmd: artillery run test.yml.  But locally I have Artillery installed on my laptop.  Where and what does that checkout step look like?

Comment: There's actually a actions/checkout@v3 step

Comment: Did you try following the same steps in your GHA workflow without `container`?

Comment: I fixed this by running Artillery from an Ubuntu image as opposed to the Artillery docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Artillery’s official GitHub Action](https://github.com/artilleryio/action-cli) for this, so you can just do:

```yaml
jobs:
  artillery:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Run performance tests
        uses: artilleryio/action-cli@v1
        with:
          command: run test/performance/perf-tests.yml
```

Their documentation has more relevant info and use cases too:

1. [Setting up a GitHub Actions workflow with Artillery](https://www.artillery.io/docs/cicd/github-actions#setting-up-a-github-actions-workflow)
2. [Scheduling Artillery load tests with GitHub Actions](https://www.artillery.io/docs/cicd/github-actions#scheduling-artillery-load-tests)